# mySQL - manually add an ID to a "WHERE column_id IN" (subquery...)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

This is a strange query that I have not had to write before but I have a situation where I need to manually add one extra variable to a "WHERE IN" statement. This example will better explain my problem.

`SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM order WHERE sub_total > 150)`

In my specific situation, I need to manually add one more user_id to the "IN" statement's sub-query regardless if they have an order subtotal grater than 150.

I have tried doing the following, and thought it would work but it returns weird results and does not work...

`SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM order WHERE sub_total > 150) OR WHERE id = 1234`

Basically, I want to sub-query to return all the user id's that match the condition AND also include one that I specify myself. 
What is the best way to accomplish this? I've tried looking it up but have not found anything to fulfill this requirement.

Comment: What is `sub_total` and how is this defined?

Comment: why don't you use union in your subquery? something like `(SELECT user_id FROM order WHERE sub_total > 150 UNION SELECT <needed ID> FROM DUAL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use OR operator:

```
SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM order WHERE sub_total > 150) 
  OR  id = 123
  OR id IN (345,567)
```

Basically IN operator like `X IN (1,2,3)` is a shortcut for:

```
X = 1
OR
X = 2
OR
X = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

`In` is not so good if you have nulls coming back...

Use exists if you want results from a subquery

```
SELECT * 
FROM user  u1
WHERE exists (SELECT 1
              FROM order o2
              WHERE o2.sub_total > 150 
              AND u1.id = o2.user_id) 
OR id IN (<list of id's to include>) -- IN is fine for an actual list
```

Also notice the `WHERE` appears once per query. `OR WHERE` is totally wrong

Comment: I can't see any difference in this [SQL Filddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c9248/1) - in the first case there is no null, in the second one there is a null coming back, and the result is exactly the same. Please explain why `IN` is not so good and `EXISTS` is much better in this case ?

Comment: @krokodilko [This is based on Oracle](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/oracle-tip-understand-how-nulls-affect-in-and-exists/) but holds true for all flavours of SQL. Other advantages of `EXISTS` come into play when the subquery returns a large dataset.

Comment: Well, please read this article **precisely**. The autor says that: *The IN and EXISTS are logically the same. .....But **problems arise when the logic is reversed to use NOT IN and NOT EXISTS**, which return different sets of rows...*. The OP use `IN` in his query, there is no `NOT IN` that could cause problems with NULLs.